# Единственное или множественное число? (3)

Tags: грамотная-речь, единственное-множественное-число

Как правильно написать: "позволяют" или "позволяет"?

> Небольшое число примитивных деталей за счет одинаковых соединений **позволяют** строить конструкции практически неограниченной сложности.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Небольшое число примитивных деталей за счет одинаковых соединений **позволяет** строить конструкции практически неограниченной сложности.*

Здесь лучше использовать формальное согласование по ед.числу (небольшое число позволяет).

Смысловое согласование (детали позволяют) нежелательно, так как это неодушевленное сущ.. которое не совершает реального активного действия.